# iPhone Shortcuts open URL in background in Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, url, shortcuts-app

How can I use iPhone Shortcuts to open the current page in a new background tab in Safari? (So I can continue navigating to other pages in the current tab)

I see that I can use shortcuts to open the URL of the current page in the same tab, but I don’t see how to open in a new tab background tab.

Comment: If you can [edit] your question to add the shortcut info that you've tried and can't get working, we can help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: I tried the Safari Open URLs action. I don’t know how to export the shortcut. But it probably shouldn’t be necessary to answer the question. I need to first find out if it is even possible to open a new Safari background tab from a shortcut. If not, then I can’t do it. If so, someone can tell me how to do it. Only if it doesn’t work will I need to show my failed shortcut.